# add_custom_target not executing

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I am trying to get cmake to execute a custom command of mine. [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937128/cmake-add-custom-command-not-being-run) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020045/cmake-add-custom-command-and-depends-target) [people](https://gist.github.com/socantre/7ee63133a0a3a08f3990) struggle with this, but I can't get any of the solutions to run.

As an MRE, create a project folder with the CMakeLists.txt and following contents:

```
# MRE add_custom_command doesn't run

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(MRECustomCmd VERSION 0.1)

set(COMPILE_INPUT_LIST
    shaders/a.cu
    shaders/b.cu
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/shaders/a.optixir
    DEPENDS shaders/a.cu
    COMMAND "echo compiling..."
    COMMAND "mkdir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/shaders"
    COMMAND "echo \"a\" >> shaders/a.optixir"
    VERBATIM
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp

    shaders/a.cu
    shaders/b.cu
)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/shaders/a.optixir
)
```

Where the files `shaders/a.cu' and 'shaders/b.cu' exist (but for this MRE are empty), and 'src/main.cpp' is just

```
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

When I do

```
cd MreProject
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

The output is:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (add_dependencies):
>
> The dependency target
>
> "C:/Users/lobner/Dev/MreCustomCmd/build/shaders/a.optixir" of target
>
> "MRECustomCmd" does not exist.

In the [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) it says:

> If DEPENDS is not specified, the command will run whenever the OUTPUT is missing; if the command does not actually create the OUTPUT, the rule will always run.

For this reason, I tried my MRE without the `DEPENDS` line as well - after all it "will always run". But that didn't work either.

Later on, in my actual code I run the custom command in a 'FOREACH' loop, I tried the way to add a new target, which depends on the output file and add the target as a dependency to my project, nothing has executed it so far. So for now, I'd like to "fix" my MRE and see what I did wrong.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, what triggered it, but it works now (though when building in VS, not when just generating with the `cmake ..` command). I did update from cmake 3.26.4 to 3.27.7, but I doubt custom_command was broken in 3.26.4, it seems rather central to me.

Answer (score 0):

`add_dependencies` is for *targets* where you specify that a *target* depends on a different *target*. `C:/Users/lobner/Dev/MreCustomCmd/build/shaders/a.optixir` is not target, it is a file - the error message informs you of that, however I see it is confusing.

Typically, you add a custom target, you see pairs of `add_custom_command` followed by `add_custom_target`.

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/shaders/a.optixir
    ...
)
add_custom_target(a_optixir DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/shaders/a.optixir)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} a_optixir)
```

Note that `add_dependencies` add *ordering*, **not** dependency, between targets. If you want PROJECT_NAME object files to be rebuilt when `a.optixir` changes, you have to add `OBJECT_DEPENDS` or `LINK_DEPENDS` properties on specific files or targets.

Comment: Okay, thanks so far. If anything, I'd want to rebuild when `a.cu` changes. I added a custom target, like you suggested (but with the `DEPENDS` to the `a.cu` file) and changed the dependency to the custom target. Now I don't get an error, but the custom command still is not run.

Comment: Though for completenes sake, I tried with the `DEPENDS` to `a.optixir` as well. It, too, doesn't generate an error but doesn't run the custom command either.

Comment: `I'd want to rebuild` Rebuild what exactly?

Comment: The .cu files are Cuda (/Optix) files. They contain code that mostly runs on the graphics card, but some of it can be run on the CPU, e.g. a data structure can be shared between the two. If that changes, then I'd need to rebuild basically the entire project (or at least anything that depends on the .cu file)

Comment: I know nothing about CUDA, the question stands. CMake has already utilities for CUDA, like https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/packages/CUDA.html .

Comment: The NVidia samples (partly) use the same way, that I am trying. In fact, I got the compilation function from there. However, the question is fundamentally about CMake, I do not understand why my custom command is not executed. Regardless of Cuda, I would like to get this right and be able to use it for other use cases. Thank you for the hints.